# Multiplying two rotation matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I have a set of 3 Euler angles which I have converted into a rotation matrix (R_in) in the ZYZ convention. I now want to apply a rotation onto these euler angles using a pre-defined rotation matrix (R_mult). What is the right way to perform the rotation?

```
1. R_rotated = R_in · R_mult
2. R_rotated = R_mult · R_in

3. R_rotated = R_in · transpose(R_mult)
4. R_rotated = transpose(R_mult) · R_in

5. R_rotated = transpose(R_in) · R_mult
6. R_rotated = R_mult · transpose(R_in)

where "·" implies a dot product.
```

Also for completeness of understanding, what are the physical implications of the wrong options?

Comment: If you're combining two rotations you use matrix multiplication, which is not usually considered a "dot product" (though you might use a dot product to help you define or remember how to do it). Just write the matrices next to each other like $R_{\mathrm{in}}R_{\mathrm{mult}}.$

Comment: By the way, I typed `$R_{\mathrm{in}}R_{\mathrm{mult}}$` to typeset the names of the matrices in the previous comment. See https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation

Comment: @DavidK Confusingly, it is common to use the term "dot" or "dot-product" to refer to matrix-multiplication in computer science literature

Comment: Assuming matrix multiplication, all the sequences shown are meaningful, as are some others such as $R_{\mathrm{mult}}^T R_{\mathrm{in}}R_{\mathrm{mult}}$ (writing $M^T$ for the transpose of matrix $M$). It depends on the purpose of the predefined rotation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct order is $R_{\mathrm{mult}}R_{\mathrm{in}}$.

For two rotations $R_1,R_2$, the product $R_1 \cdot R_2$ is the matrix corresponding to the rotation obtained by first applying $R_2$, then applying $R_1$. That is, rotations are done "from right to left". In our case, the first rotation (corresponding to $R_{\mathrm{in}}$) is the rotation that moves the $x,y,z$ axes to their new orientations (corresponding to the Euler angles), and the second rotation is $R_{\mathrm{mult}}$ is the pre-defined rotation (applied to our appropriately pre-rotated space).

Multiplication by $R^T$ for a rotation matrix $R$ corresponds to the *inverse* of a rotation $R$, i.e. undoing the rotation in question.

For example, if we wanted to find the matrix of the rotation matrix $R$ *relative to* the coordinates defined by the axes corresponding to our Euler angles, then the corresponding matrix would be computed as $R^T_{\mathrm{in}} R_{\mathrm{mult}} R_{\mathrm{in}}$. In other words, to rotate something in this new coordinate system, we could first apply $R_{\mathrm{in}}$ (convert alternative coordinates to the standard coordinates), apply $R_{\mathrm{mult}}$, then undo $R_{\mathrm{in}}$ (convert the standard-coordinate result back to the alternative coordinates).